# How Feature stappling will effect the existing site collections?

Tags: powershell, site-collection, feature-stapling

I have added a Farm scope feature stapler that staples an existing feature and that existing feature deploys master page. When i create a new site collection, the master page deploys automatically. I have many site collections that are already created before feature stapling. Now my question is how the feature stapling will effect the existing site collections?

[image]
Is there any way to do this by Power Shell?

Comment: First try to manually activate the feature on already created site collection. Make sure it works. Then you can easily automate it using PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stapling only affects new Sites.

You can use PowerShell to iterate all your sites and activate your MasterPage Feature

```
Ge-SPWebApplication "your web app url" | Get-SPSite -Limit all | %{ Enable-SPFeature -ID "<Your Feature ID>" -Url $_.Url }
```

Comment: How i specify from which web app it should iterate all the site collections?

Comment: Get-SPWebApplication "http://...." | Get-SPSite -Limit all | %{ Enable-SPFeature -ID "<Your Feature ID>" -Url $_ }

Comment: Wehn i run this command, i got following error:  Enable-SPFeature : Feature 'App.mysite_FeatureStapler' <ID: 3bbc42b7-4cfr8-4afc4-a4f489bfbfbf4> is already activated at scope Farm. But i could not see master page deployed on existing site Collections? that means it feature did not activated on existing site Collections?

Comment: what's the ID for you masterpage's feature?

Comment: I have now changed the feature id in the command with Masterpage feature and now getting invalid URI error: See above i have modified the question and added an error sketch

Comment: try changing the $_ at the end to $_.Url I don't have an SP environment on me atm to test....